# Substitution or Elimination method

Tags: substitution

Consider the system of equations 4x + y = –2 and 4x + 5y = –6. Would you use the substitution method or the elimination method to solve this system algebraically? Why?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: It depends on your level of easiness with these methods. In this case as the coefficients of $x$ in both the equations are same, it will be easier to use elimination.

Answer (score 0):

multiplying the first equation by $-1$ we get
$$-4x-y=-2$$
$$4x+5y=-6$$
adding both equations we obtain
$$4y=-4$$
and from here you will get $y$ and then $x$